# Failed insert in Snowflake with JSON containing '$$'

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm escaping JSON before inserting into my Snowflake table. However, if the JSON itself contains the Snowflake escape quotes ($$) it will fail. Is there a way around this? If I remove the '$$' from the JSON then it inserts successfully however I need to retain the original JSON. Is there a way around this without removing the $$ characters? Thanks

```
insert into yaml_files
      select column1 as path,
      parse_json(column2) as yaml
      from values ('test',$${'example': 'blahblah','example2': 'asdf$$6lkj'}$$);
```

Comment: `$${'example': 'blahblah','example2': 'asdf$$6lkj'}$$` => `'{"example": "blahblah","example2": "asdf$$6lkj"}'`

Comment: is postgresql the `$$` can have a token to name the dollar-quoted block, thus `$abc$123$$456$abc$` gets you away from this problem. I assume you are using dollar quotes to avoid escaping the inner quotes, can you do the same for `$$` inside the data

Comment: @LukaszSzozda point is awesome if you are actually running the code exactly as it's written, "then don't do that". There is the point that "valid json is double quoted on the names not single quoted. And if you are loading data into snowflake via insert commands, as a general rule don't, it's super slow as compared to a COPY from a S3 bucket fashion to load data. But at the same time is valid as part of a many step lift and shift. (aka years ago we did just this, and were sending 10MB insert statements, but the cost/preformance is shocking bad)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda that worked. I removed the enclosing escape characters and converted from python JSON to actual JSON(double quotes) and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments noted, you can use single quotes for strings instead of `$$`.

Error reproduced:

```sql
select parse_json($${"a":"b$$c"}$$);
```

Fixed:

```sql
select parse_json('{"a":"b$$c"}');
```

If there's a single quote inside the string, escape it with `\`:

```sql
select parse_json('{"a":"b\'$$c"}');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using parse_json can you escape those $$ symbols like below,

```
`select parse_json($${"a":"b\$\$c"}$$);`
```

If you using python just replace "$" with "\$".